# Android: When I click on button it should play video in WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

How can I play video in WebView by clicking on button? I want something like when I click on button it will click on specific coordinates (in my case on play button).

Here is picture:

[image]

When I click on button below webview it should play video from openload.io in webview.

How can I do it?

Thank you for answer.

Comment: what type of "video" you want to play? Youtube, Video, simple mp4 file?

Comment: Video from openload.io

Answer (score 0):

You just need to open your webview with the url that contain the video.

Android's WebView use the chromium engine, so opening an url in a webview inside your application or opening it in the chrome app, is the same behaviour.

Comment: But I want play video when I click on button under WebView I do not want open video in Chrome or another browser.

Comment: Which url you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Check for Intent class. It may help you to lunch any other application or url.